# Website not working after migration from one EC2 server to another

Tags: c#, amazon-ec2, web-config, umbraco

I'm wondering if any of you can shed some light on a problem I'm having.
I had a website located on an Amazon EC2 instance, it was working with no problems however the person who set it up located it the wrong region. As a result I've set up a new EC2 instance and zipped up the website directory.
I copied it across to the new instance and unzipped it.

Then I set up the website in IIS, it has it's own username so it doesn't run under IUSR. This use has full permissions to run the website and other than location, the setup is identical to that on the previous server.

However, when I go to adjust the connection string through IIS I get a message:

> There was an error while performing this operation.
>
> Details
>
> Filename: \?{path to web config here}
>
> Error:

I've not seen anything like this. I can open the web config in notepad++ and make changes with no issue. But the site reports the web config as malformed. Even using the exact web config from the working server this same message appears.

I've tried re-compacting the site on the working server and transferring again with exactly the same results.

Anyone got some advice on what I could try?

Comment: If the person who marked this down see this, please could they explain why so I know for next time. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be willing to bet that an extra module that you had installed on the old instance is not available on the new instance; I had a similar problem when I was using ther url-rewrite module of IIS on one instance, and moved the site to another instance that did not have that module installed and got a very similar (if not identical) error message - that would explain why the config was valid on one server, but not on the other.

You need to make sure all of the 'extra' options that were turned on in the old instance are available on the new instance, and I'd start by checking the rewrite module.